# Google Maps Polyline CLICK Event

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, polyline

I'm implementing a map application. It uses Google Maps API for Flash. There is a one callback function that is triggered when the map is clicked. Additionally, there are plenty of polylines that are generated dynamically. The polylines have also click event listener assigned to them. The problem is when I click a polyline, the map click event is triggered at first and then the polyline's click event is fired.

I can't resolve that issue. It's really anoying. Here is code that assigns callback to the map's click event:

```
map = new Map();
map.key = GOOGLE_MAP_KEY;
map.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, onMapClicked, true);
```

and here is code that assigns callback function to a polyline's click event:

```
var polyline:Polyline = new Polyline(path);
polyline.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, cutToEnd);
```

I need to supress the "onMapClicked" function's invocation when I click on a polyline. Only "cutToEnd" method should be invoked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
map.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, onMapClicked, true);
```

You use bubblingPhase here (third "true" parameter). It means, that when you click polyline, event "reaches" first your map, because it's capturing from stage to your button. Set parameter "false", or leave only 2 parameters (useCapture is "false" by default). Then in the end of your polyline click handler add `event.stopPropagation()` method call. It will make event stop bubbling to stage, and it won't "reach" your map.

UDATE: If MapMouseEvent does not bubble you can compare `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` properties. In your polyline click listener they will be equal. So you may add

```
 if(event.target != event.currentTarget)
    return;
```

at the beginning of your map click listener.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think it works though. First of all, I removed the 3rd parameter from all of the "addEventListener" invocations. Then, I added "event.stopPropagation()" at the end of "cutToEnd" method. Additionally, I added the targets' comparison at the beginning of "onMapClicked". I was debugging it and it always says that "event.target" = "event.currentTarget". "onMapClicked" is always invoked as first. Did I miss something?

Comment: It seems, that map and polyline are not in the parent-child relations on the displaylist